# Property %s is required

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am write one easy program using GAE and python 2.7, but I met some problem while stored data into db. My code is below:

```
class MemberInfo(db.Model):
    firstName = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class RegisterPageButtonDown(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        memberInfo = MemberInfo()       
        memberInfo.firstName = self.request.get('firstName')
        memberInfo.put()
```

The error raise in "**memberInfo = MemberInfo()**", it said "**Property firstName is required**". I am sure I put data in html form and the method is post, too.

I've been stuck in this problem for whole night, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `firstName` property to required, so when you instantiate an object you must provide that property with a value, e.g.:

```
memberInfo = MemberInfo(firstName = self.request.get('firstName'))
```

Alternatively, you can make `firstName` not required in your model.

Comment: Hi, if I have many entries in the db and form, how can I put all data using one command ?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. Can you create another one?

Comment: This is true even for keyproperty and userproperty? I use `required=True` only for these properties and I instantiate the entities without provide the properties, like the code in question.

Comment: Yes, it should apply to those as well. From the docs: "A model instance must initialize all required properties in its constructor so that the instance is not created with missing values. An attempt to create an instance without initializing a required property, or an attempt to assign None to a required property, raises a BadValueError." Perhaps you have supplied a default value?

Comment: No, You can see an example of my code [here](https://github.com/presveva/gae.icio.us/blob/master/home.py) rows 15 and 214

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the first line of the function, before you even get the value from the request. This is because you need to pass in that value when you instantiate the object.

```
firstName = self.request.get('firstName')
memberInfo = MemberInfo(firstName=firstName)
```

(Also note that normal naming conventions for Python mean that variables and properties are `lower_case_with_underscore`, not `camelCase`.)

Comment: Hi, if I have many entries in the db and form, how can I put all data using one command ?